# Find all read-after-write (RAW) data dependencies

Tags: dependencies, mips, cpu-architecture

Consider the following code in MIPS:

```
lw $1, 40($2) # I1
add $2, $3, $3 # I2 
add $1, $1, $2 # I3
sw $1, 20($2) # I4
```

My own answer is RAW on $1 from I1 to I3 and I4, on $2 from I2 to I3 and I4, on $1 from I3 to I4.

However the solution doesn't include $1 from I1 to I4. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the solution doesn't include $1 from I1 to I4.

I4's stored-data ($1) comes from I3, and store-address ($2) from I2.  Neither of its inputs come **directly** from I1.

The $1 output of the I1 load isn't needed by anything after I3.

(In an out-of-order CPU with register renaming, there are no more references to it once the I3 add retires (because the architectural $1 register holding it has been overwritten), so the physical register holding it can be freed.)

There is a dependency chain starting with the load, and ending with the store, and looking at that is useful, but it's a separate thing from hazard analysis.

Finding the separate dependency chains in code is highly relevant for out-of-order execution, especially finding out whether dep chains are loop-carried, or whether each iteration has a separate dependency chain (allowing OoOE to overlap execution of multiple iterations).  Separate dependency chains are basically the same thing as Instruction Level Parallelism that a CPU can find and exploit.